# There was a network error [PhoneGap/Cordova]

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on Hybrid app for android.
Following is **scenario** (what my app do).

A user first signing in the application after signing in successfully user moves to feed page where I get feeds from the database (like social feeds e.g images/post/videos/ videos links etc). It loads first 10 feed and when scrolls down it get next feed from the db and when it gets any video links then an error occurred.
Following **Error**

```
There was a network error. (file://cdn.embedly..... ) //Full path of video
```

and when I click ok then app close.

What should I do to handle this.

**Some points**

1. Application has access internet properly. (so this is not a problem i think)
2. I also did [this](https://www.robertkehoe.com/2013/01/fix-for-phonegap-connection-to-server-was-unsuccessful/) approach for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758615/a-network-error-in-phonegap-on-android) type of error. (but not work here in above error case)

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Were you able to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: In my database video path are saved like this `//cdn.embedly....` without any protocol. so when it get in desktop browser it automatically add `http` or also working fine without `http` but in mobile,phonegap it adds 'file://' protocol that cause error in my case so i update my database with full link. or when get in mobile simple `if else` if no protocol defines then add `http`

Comment: Thanks! My case i can't modify the code since it falls in a third party iframe plus it happens only for higher android versions not for lower versions so i am not sure it is just phonegap. But thanks for the information.