# "Application Error: There was a network error" on android 4.x

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am using areyouahuman playthru captcha (more details below) on my web app (the app is based on html5, phonegap 3.x and jqm 1.2). The problem is the playthru captcha throws out an error while loading i.e. "Application Error: There was a network error (file://n-cdn.areyouahuman.com/kitten)" and restart/reloads the app. This happens only on android 4.x. But in Android 2.x and iOS its seems to work fine. I did not get a chance to test it on android 3.x. Therefore this seems to be something related to android versions 4.x. and not related to any access permissions of phonegap or any network related issue.

Is there some kind of a known issue with android 4.x? I heard android 4.x doesn't allow parameters within the url ([source](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/a_network_error_occurred_file_android_asset_www_listing_html_cat_6)) but i can't edit the captcha javascript so i am helpless here. Is there a workaround? Is there anything else i should check for this error. Thanks for any help!

Note: Areyouahuman playthru captcha is basically an interactive game based captcha that downloads a proprietary html5,javascript code and runs it within an iframe within the app. ([their website](http://areyouahuman.com))

Comment: share your code what you have done here.

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin It got resolved. The support at areyouahuman  captcha were able to resolve this form their side. It seems the issue was the way the relative urls were being handled. plus something with android 4+. I also did some search and found that phonegap may append file:// to any urls with unspecified protocols. So its basically urls are not constructed correctly that may cause the urls to break and cause network errors. -> \[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911325/there-was-a-network-error-phonegap-cordova\]. Whatever might be the cause the issue seems to be fixed now. Thanks!